# Prepend a random number to pairs of files

Tags: file, random, rename

I have in a folder, pairs of files, mp4 and srt subtitle files.
e.g.

- video1.mp4
- video1.srt
- video2.mp4
- video2.srt

I want to prepend a random number to each video file but I must also prepend the same number to the set file.
Does anyone know how I can do this?
I'm using a mac, so it could be a bash script, automator, or even PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Here's a single line bash command that does what I need.

```
for f in *.mp4 *.m4v; do ran=$(printf "%03.0f" $((RANDOM%300)));  myFile="${f}"; mv -f "${myFile}" "${ran}-${myFile}"; mv -f "${myFile%.*}.srt" "${ran}-${myFile%.*}.srt"; done
```